# Mobilefirst 7.0 soapadapter fails calling no argument operatio

Tags: soap, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I created a soapadapter via the wizard using the webservice wsdl file. Most operation run succesfully bu one. This particular operatio returns an array of objects and consume no arguments.
The sample procedure parameters is:

```
{
  "recuperaVariabili": {
  }
}
```

Calling the procedure, never invokes onSuccess nor onFailure functions. Looking at MobileFirst server log, I can see the following stacktrace:`

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project FinancialGuardian]SoapAdapter1/RischiServiceService_recuperaVariabiliFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project FinancialGuardian]
TypeError: Cannot read property "children" from undefined (2015-06-12T15:19:59.479Z/198f6d0c5bd3a9763e35dfa0268338bb84d5cfae/SoapAdapter1-impl.js#1134)
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project FinancialGuardian]nullorg.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "children" from undefined (2015-06-12T15:19:59.479Z/198f6d0c5bd3a9763e35dfa0268338bb84d5cfae/SoapAdapter1-impl.js#1134)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3725)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectElem(ScriptRuntime.java:1432)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.doGetElem(Interpreter.java:2204)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1260)
    at script.handleMappings(2015-06-12T15:19:59.479Z/198f6d0c5bd3a9763e35dfa0268338bb84d5cfae/SoapAdapter1-impl.js:1134)
    at script.buildBody(2015-06-12T15:19:59.479Z/198f6d0c5bd3a9763e35dfa0268338bb84d5cfae/SoapAdapter1-impl.js:1117)
    at script.RischiServiceService_recuperaVariabili(2015-06-12T15:19:59.479Z/198f6d0c5bd3a9763e35dfa0268338bb84d5cfae/SoapAdapter1-impl.js:960)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:107)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:267)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:241)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:211)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:125)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:54)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:676)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:622)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:69)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:504)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:501)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:155)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:95)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:56)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:148)
    at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:472)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:975)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1097)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:938)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide some the  adapter implementation?

Comment: Yes, I can. Do you need a mock webservice too?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qack85vh458b5d7/test2.zip?dl=0

Comment: That was the link to dropbox. Inside the zip file there's a readme.txt with explanations. I hope Iwas clear enough.

Comment: You need to simplify your code here. Create a new project that only contains the adapter and a function to invoke the adapter. Then invoke it. See if you now manage to call either onSuccess or onFailure.

Comment: @IdanAdar I did it with the same result. The new project is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/gevogllbwpe1uxw/TestSoap.zip?dl=0 in main.js there is doRecuperaVariabili() function that call the adapter. This function is called at the end of wlCommonInit() function, so I did launch it via preview. onSuccess nor onFailure where called, I just see the error both in browser console and MobileFirst server console, as before.

Comment: I would try to simplify it even further - do a simple style invocation and not inline inside a variable using anonymous functions.

Comment: @IdanAdar  I did it with the same result as before. The new project is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ustsrgecepzo454/TestSoap.zip?dl=0 Now main.js is less than 30 lines. I would not be able to simplify more. Or maybe I misunderstood your statement.

Comment: Simple invocation structure: http://pastebin.com/mc8aeYfS -- just that. Nothing else.

Comment: @IdanAdar I see. I put a log print inside functions just to demonstrate that the problem is split in 2 parts: 1st - soap call fails on server side, 2nd - onFailure nor onSuccess functions are called. From my point of view that's not normal.

Comment: Provide a .zip with my suggested structure and an adapter we can run locally to test.

Comment: That's it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ustsrgecepzo454/TestSoap.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I examined the WSDL that you've provided and for the *recuperaVariabili* service the input parameter is defined as:

```
<element name="recuperaVariabili">
  <complexType/>
</element>
```

I believe that the empty *complexType* is what confuses that adapter generator as it might expect some elements/attributes to be defined for that complex type. I must say that this is a valid declaration in XSD/WSDL so the MF should be able to handle such cases.

I can think of two quick fixes until it will be fixed in MF:

1) Update the adapter's *RischiServiceService_recuperaVariabili* function so that the mappings variable should be something like this:

```
var mappings = { 
  roots: {
   'recuperaVariabili': { nsPrefix: 'impl', type: 'impl:recuperaVariabili' }                
  },
  types: { 'impl:recuperaVariabili': {
    children: []
    }
  }
};
```

2) Update the WSDL so that the declared element will be *simpleType*.

Comment: I've just modified RischiServiceService_recuperaVariabili definition, as of  1),  and the service replies correctly. I mean no need to change wsdl as of 2). Thank you very much.